# Salt archive.extract module with strip-component parameter causing issue. Is there workaround?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, salt-stack, lxc

Following code I am using in order to extract different tars in directory {{ work_dir }}. If I use {{ work_dir }}/{{layer}} it works properly. But if I use {{ work_dir }} then it causes issue (It requires distinct directory for each extraction)

with {{ work_dir }}/ {{layer}} gives me extracted version as /tmp/mount/f1/f1 (As extraction has f1/ content ) where as I want /tmp/mount/f1 as root. For this I used strip-component which causes issue. Please suggest alternative.

```
  {% for layer in slices[slice] %}
    {{ work_dir }}/{{ layer }}:
      archive.extracted:
         - name: {{ work_dir }}
         - archive_format: tar
         - source: {{ location }}/{{ layer }}-{{ version }}-{{ build }}.tar.gz
         - tar_options: strip-components=1
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible option is to extract it first and then move dir. But I feel there should be more cleaner way for this.